# How to make "xxd" place spaces between the hex values?

Tags: linux, terminal, xxd

I am using the following command to read the output of one terminal from another terminal:

```
xxd -p /dev/pts/0
```

But there is no spaces between the hex values, for example I get something like this:

```
61626162
```

Instead of this:

```
61 62 61 62
```

Comment: How about `od -An -vtx1`?

Answer (score 2):

If you're open to bringing in other tools then one possibility is to send output through `sed`:

```
xxd -p /dev/pts/0 | sed 's/../& /g'
```